# Parse each line with multiple string values in a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
    cat file.txt 
    
    "1" "USA" "abc"
    "2" "Canada" "pqr" 
....
```

I'm trying to assign the above string values to a variable iterating through each line at a time.
For eg. ->

```
sr="1" country="USA"    name="abc" 
sr="2" country="Canada" name="pqr"
```

Any advise on how I can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: A little bit more clarifying of what you really want would be appreciated. Do you just want to store all values in an array? Do you want to iterate through each value? What exactly are you trying to achieve? - An example of what you've already tried would be great too.

Comment: Thanks for your message! I've added an example above to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `while read -r sr country name ; do … ; done < file.txt`?

Comment: Do you need to use bash? Otherwise i'd recommend python. There you can use objects which would be a lot cleaner - assumed that your input is always the same.

Comment: The values of the variables are ambiguous. Do you want `sr=1 country=USA name=abc` or `sr=\"1\" country=\"USA\" name=\"abc\"`? An `echo "$sr"` will output `1` in the first case and `"1"` in the latter.

Comment: From your example, I conclude that you don't want the quotes from the text file be part of the stored value in the variable. So, how would the assignmtent be for the line `ab""cd "ef   gh" ijk`?

Comment: What is the format of the file? Can the fields contain spaces or double-quotes that are considered as part of the data?

Comment: Whoever created this file format should be prepared to receive serious threats to their bodily integrity, perhaps from you.

Comment: If the example is representative, you might be able to convert it to bog standard CSV with `sed 's/" "/","/g' file.txt >file.csv` and then take it from there with standard CSV tools. (The shell is not very good at handling CSV, though.)

Comment: Perhaps roughly equivalently, `sed 's/^"//;s/"$//;s/" "/\t/g' file.txt | while IFS=$'\t' read -r sr country name; do`... Demo: https://ideone.com/bo8iIo

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
cat 1.txt|awk '{print "str="$1,"country="$2,"name="$3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the quoting of the data is compatible to the Bash rules for [Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html), you can just use [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

exec <<EOF
"1" "USA" "abc"
"2" "Canada" "pqr" 
EOF

while read -r line; do
  source <(printf 'set %s\n' "$line")
  printf 'sr="%s" country="%s" name="%s"\n' "$@"
done
```

If the quoting of the data is compatible to the [JSON quoting rules](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), you can use `jq` to parse the data:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

exec <<EOF
"1" "USA" "abc"
"2" "Canada" "pqr" 
EOF

jq -sr '.[]' | while true; do
  read -r sr || break
  read -r country
  read -r name
  printf 'sr="%s" country="%s" name="%s"\n' \
         "$sr" "$country" "$name"
done
```

This will be less prone to security exploits.

Comment: You're asking for trouble :-P

Comment: @Fravadona The [ideas of other people](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/237735/7167) are not much better. Bash is not the right tool to write parsers. You can slurp the data through `jq` to feel a bit better. But since he did not say anything about the quoting rules: this will work at least for the two lines in the question.

Comment: `source <(printf 'set %s\n' "$line")` is no different from using an `eval` besides using a subshell and process substitution.